# How to invoke two actors at a time , i.e. parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, akka

I have a scenario where two functionalities run parallel.

Below is sample pseudo code.

```
MainActor{
 // retrive company ids
 //for each company id i need to run another two different actions simultaniously 
   tell(A_Actor)
   tell(B_Actor)
//if I call above they are calling sequentially i.e. first it runs tell(A_Actor)
//then comes to tell(B_Actor).
//If tell(A_Actor) fails it wont run tell(B_Actor).
}
A_Actor{
// do ingest into a file.
}

B_Actor{
// do ingest into a DB.
}
```

**Question :**
How to run two functionalities i.e. tell(A_Actor) & tell(B_Actor) run parallel?

Comment: I don't understand your point. The tell method is asynchronous. from the doc: `Sends a one-way asynchronous message. E.g. fire-and-forget semantics.`

Comment: Javascript doesn't support multi threading...

Answer (score 1):

The `tell` method is asynchronous. When you fire a `tell`to `actorA`, it doesn't wait until `actorA` finishes or crashes to execute the next action, which here is to `tell actorB`

If you need to paralelize the two `tell` methods, then you can do the following :

```
    val tellActions = Vector(() => actorA.tell(messageA, senderActor), () => actorB.tell(messageB, senderActor))
    tellActions.par.foreach(_.apply())
```

Note that this is Scala code

Comment: thanks a lot .let me try it in java. I will update you.

Comment: Yeah, I think this question doesn't really make sense. As you point out, tell() is asynchronous. It doesn't actually do the work: it just adds a message into the mailbox. Although your example would work, it's also pointless since tell() should be nearly instantaneous. Even if the tell() is called "sequentially" the actual work will be in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This has been pointed out in several comments (including mine), but I felt it deserved an answer.

In short, you need to distinguish between calling the `tell` method in parallel with the functionality that the actors execute within their receive methods being executed in parallel. The functionality will be executed in parallel automatically, and calling the `tell` method in parallel doesn't make any sense.

The code you show **will** execute the ingest in a file and ingest into the DB in parallel. This is automatic and requires no action on your part; this is how actors and `tell` works. And, despite what you say, if something goes wrong with the file ingestion it will not affect the ingestion into the DB. (Assuming you built the actors and messages correctly, since you don't list their implementation.)

The `tell` method is asynchronous: it returns nearly immediately and doesn't do the actual logic (ingestion in this case): the only thing it does is place the message in the recipient's mailbox. Ismail's answer, in theory, shows you how you could "invoke `tell`" in parallel, but in that example you "sequentially" are creating the array that is used for parallel tells and the whole process will be *very* inefficient.) His code, while technically doing what you ask, is nonsensical in practice: it accomplishes nothing except slowing the code down significantly.

In short, I think you either:

- Have something fundamentally wrong with your actors and how you are calling them.
- You are actually are executing the functionality in parallel and you just aren't realizing it because you are measuring/observing something incorrectly.